# Python + Flask + Mysql Error 2006 (Server has gone away)

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I have an application with python, flask, and flask_mysqldb. When I execute the first query, everything works fine, but the second query always throws an error (2006, server has gone away). Everything I found on the web says this error is a timeout issue, which doesn't seem to be my case because:

1 - I run the second query just a few seconds after running the first

2 - My timeout configuration is set to 8 hours

I don't know what else this could be, here is the code that I am running:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
import endpoints.usuario as usuario

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='/root/sftp/atom-projects/flask-example/public/')

app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = '123'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = '123'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = '123'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = '123'

app.add_url_rule('/usuarios', 'usuarios', usuario.list_all, methods=['GET'])

@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(e):
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')
```

here is the code for the usuarios file:

```
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from flask import Flask, make_response
from flask import current_app
from flask import request
import bcrypt

def list_all():

    mysql = MySQL(current_app)
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute("select * from usuario")
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    usuarios = []
    for row in records:
        usuarios.append({"id":row[0], "nome":row[1], "email":row[2], "senha":row[3], "tipo":row[4]})

    for usuario in usuarios:
        tipo = None
        cursor.execute("select * from tipo_usuario where id = %s", [usuario['tipo']])
        records = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in records:
            usuario['tipo'] = {"id":row[0], "permissao":row[1]}

    return make_response({"msg":'', "error":False, "data":usuarios})
```

I have this running on nginx + gunicorn, here is the log :

```
gunicorn -w 1 --reload main:app
[2019-12-19 12:53:21 +0000] [5356] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2019-12-19 12:53:21 +0000] [5356] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (5356)
[2019-12-19 12:53:21 +0000] [5356] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2019-12-19 12:53:21 +0000] [5359] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 5359
[2019-12-19 12:53:28 +0000] [5359] [ERROR] Error handling request /usuarios
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 134, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 175, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2457, in wsgi_app
    ctx.auto_pop(error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/ctx.py", line 452, in auto_pop
    self.pop(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/ctx.py", line 438, in pop
    app_ctx.pop(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/ctx.py", line 238, in pop
    self.app.do_teardown_appcontext(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2320, in do_teardown_appcontext
    func(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask_mysqldb/__init__.py", line 100, in teardown
    ctx.mysql_db.close()
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, '')
```

If I run it with more workers, I can run a few more (depending on how many workers) queries, what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error on my python flask application. And when I tried using `from flask import current_app as app` I still get an error. Eventually, I manged to remove the error by creating a separate file for flask app object `app = Flask(__name__)` and then importing it inside all the files that needed the object.

For Instance.

App object module: `main.py`

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)
```

Other files like `usuarios.py` or `config.py`

```
from main import app
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = '123'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = '123'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = '123'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = '123'

mysql = MySQL(app)
```

**Note:** I used `flask_mysqldb` instead of `flaskext.mysql` but I don't think that makes any difference as long as your using the right parameters for either.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution.

Turns out Flask Mysql needs to be performed within the ***try...catch..finally*** block

And also make sure to close the cursor if you are using flask_mysqldb, which doesn't handle closing for you.

This is how my Query looks  like now.

```
try:
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE `email` = %s', (email))
    results = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
except Exception:
    return 'Error: unable to fetch items'
    cur.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the below link and use mysqlpool instead of mysqldb or mysqlext.

https://pypi.org/project/flask-mysqlpool/

```
    connection = mysql.connection.get_connection()
    cur=connection.cursor()
    query = "Enter your Query"
    cur.execute(query)
    connection.commit()
    cur.close()
```

and one more thing that

app.config['MYSQL_POOL_SIZE'] = 30
this pool size must be less than or equal to 32

Comment: mysql = MySQLPool(app)